# Creating UI element when user clicks in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

What I want to do is make it so when the user clicks the 'rectangle' shape it creates a white border around the box like so....

If the user clicks in an area where no rectangle is present then it deselects any selected rectangles. I'm assuming this may need some additional changes in the code, any suggestions are welcome!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for you. Let me know if this works for you. If not I will try and modify it. It is basic, but not that hard to implement I believe.

Here is the XAML. Note you will have to do all the positioning of the rectangles and such yourself. This just selects and deselects with a black border.

```
<Grid Background="#00000000" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" >
        <Border Visibility="Hidden" x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="230,135,142,58">

        </Border>

        <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="Blue" MouseDown="Rectangle_MouseDown" Margin="250,148,160,74"/>
    </Grid>
```

And here is the code behind.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       private void Rectangle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            border.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver == rect)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                border.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }


    }
```